Probability Problem with Combinatorica
Five numbers are being chosen from the set {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11} with replacement (each number can appear several times). What is the probability of getting 3 odd numbers ?
We know that there are $11^{5}$ options in this trial.
We also know that there we have $6^{3}\cdot 5^{2}$ options for 3 odd numbers and 2 that are not. What I am missing here is the number of such combinations. I mean, my formula above assumes that the first 3 are odd and the rest even, but there are several ways for the order. Can I use binomial coefficient when the sampling is with replacement ?

Clarification requested: do you mean exactly 3 odd numbers, or at least 3 odd numbers?

See Binomial Distribution,
specifically $\displaystyle \binom{n}{k}p^kq^{(n-k)}.$

Exactly 3 odd numbers

why is it binomial distribution ? the same odd number can be chosen 3 times, it's not the same, is it ?

Thinking about this again, can't I simply say that there are 6^3 options for 3 odd numbers and then it's 6^3 / 11^5 ?

Assuming order matters, the first thing you can do is choose the $3$ picks that have odd numbers, $\binom 53$. After this step, your solution is correct, but I will add it for the sake of completeness. Then, for each of the three picks, pick the actual odd number, $6\cdot6\cdot6=6^3$. The same for the even numbers, $5^2$. Then you divide by the total number of ways to pick $5$ numbers with replacement, $11^5$, to get the final answer: $$\frac{\binom 53 \cdot 6^3 \cdot 5^2}{11^5}$$

I am not sure I get it. The binomial coefficient gives us the number of combinations, i.e., (1,3,5), (1,5,3), (3,7,9), etc. It doesn't take into account (1,1,1), (1,1,3). The sampling is with replacement, so 3 odd numbers can theoretically be the same number.

@user2899944  You are making a sequence of five selections.  The factor $\binom{5}{3}$ is the number of ways of selecting in which three positions in the sequence odd numbers will appear.
